# Passing an EditText Object and EditText.setText() throw Exception

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have an Activity the implements the following functions:

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
         public void setText(EditText txtBox,String strText){
             txtBox.setText(strText);
         }
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.settings);
             EditText txtEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEdit);
             setText(txtEdit,"String");
             ...
        }
```

So I am trying to pass an EditText Object to the `setText` Function and then calling the `txtBox.setText()` function. But this throws the following exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

However, when calling the `txtEdit.setText()` function within `onCreate()` works perfectly fine.

Edit: The function setText was a simplification, I was actually passing an object a of custom class a then called `txtBox.setText(object.value)`, which ( by mistake) was actually an Integer, not a String. Passing a String fixed the error. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: clean/rebuild project? I mean everything seems fine in your code..

Comment: Yes!..I tested your code in my side...everything is ok

Comment: In my previous answer... I was thinking that you are using the same Edittext in setText() method

Comment: Are you sure you are passing String parameter? this error pops up when you pass int 0 into setText, that tries to load the string from string resources.

Comment: do you have id **txtEdit** in your layout file ?

Comment: And try to post all the stacktrace since the exception has many ways to take place.

Comment: @LubosHoracek is probably right.. Check elsewhere if you are using setText method with 2nd paramter as int

Comment: can you show layout file ?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that, in fact I did not pass a String Parameter. Like @Lubos Horacek described the exception is thrown when you are passing an int to setText. Converting the parameter fixed the error.

Comment: But in your code you shared you are passing "String" as parameter and it is String dude.

Answer (score -1):

May be your id doesn't exist in layout file

Comment: This would bring null pointer exception as findViewById return null in that case.